# I am having an issue loading a photo in Delphi using "IF" and "THEN" commands

Tags: delphi

Okay so, i keep getting the error {type of expression must be BOOLEAN}

my code is

```
procedure TForm1.RadioGroup1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If (RadioGroup1.ItemIndex := 0)
  Then (Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile ('Plus.jpg'));
end;
```

have the same error whether i use: 
   `Then (Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile (Plus.jpg));`
   `Then := (Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile (Plus.jpg));`

```
`Then = (Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile (Plus.jpg));`
```

Comment: The error is after the "Then"

Comment: := is the assignment operater. Use a plain = for comparison.

Comment: `If (RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 0)` -> `=` is comparison, `:=` is assignment

Comment: @R.Lastrucci It sounds like you're trying to learn the syntax by randomly typing things into the code editor.  This is not necessary.  The language is very well documented.  I suggest you start by [reviewing the basics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)).

Comment: @J... Thanks, I haven't been coding all that long, only started a couple weeks ago at school. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Bear in mind that `if` and `then` are not separate "commands" but rather a grammatical structure to express what to do (the single or compound statement that follows `then`) if the boolean condition which follows the `if` is true.  Get that straight and you'll be in for happy sailing.

Answer (score 2):

```
If (RadioGroup1.ItemIndex := 0)
```

You use `:=` which is the assignment operator. You are looking for equality comparison, `=`. Like this:

```
If (RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 0)
```

It is rather unusual style to write the `Then` on a new line. I would format your code like this:

```
if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 0 then
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('Plus.jpg');
```

I have also removed a number of spurious parens.

Comment: It's working now, Thanks

Comment: The parens in the `if`-clause are superfluous here, but some might insist on having them there anyway, to make the test easily extensible to something like `if (RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 0) and (Image1 <> nil) then`. I personally prefer your style, i.e. remove them if they are not needed.